# How to get result in three columns?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is my code....

```
<?php

    $arr1 = array(); 
    $arr2 = array();
    $arr3 = array();

     $intial_amount = 1000;
     $sum = 0;


        for($j = 3; $j<=24; $j = $j + 3)
        {
                if($j == 3)
                 {

                    $arr1[$j] = "";
                    $sum = $sum + 1000*3;
                 }
                else
                {
                $sum = $sum + 1000*3;
                $sum = $sum + ($sum * 0.02);
                 $arr1[$j] = $sum;
                }

        }
        for($j = 27; $j<=48; $j = $j + 3)
        {

                $sum = $sum + 1000*3;
                $sum = $sum + ($sum * 0.02);
                 $arr2[$j] = $sum;



        }
        for($j = 51; $j<=72; $j = $j + 3)
        {

                $sum = $sum + 1000*3;
                $sum = $sum + ($sum * 0.02);
                 $arr3[$j] = $sum;



        }
        $arr = array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
        foreach($arr as $key => $val)
        {
            foreach($val as $k => $v)
                {
                    echo $k."&nbsp;".$v."<br>";
                }

            echo "<br>";

        } 
?>
```

i want the result in three columns..

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**! Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome again, and I will mark this topic to close. Please, read how to ask as @BenPearlKahan said and then come back and post a correct question

Comment: And don't think this site is for we make your homework, first try something and then ask us how to solve the problems you see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your code so well, as it's unclear what you're doing, but if you want to display a list in three columns, use CSS's `columns`:

```
<html>
<ul style="columns: 3; -webkit-columns: 3; -moz-columns: 3;">
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something</li>
</ul>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like that 
[image]

if you do use the following code:

```
$arr1 = array(); 
$arr2 = array();
$arr3 = array();

 $intial_amount = 1000;
 $sum = 0;


    for($j = 3; $j<=24; $j = $j + 3)
    {
            if($j == 3)
             {

                $arr1[$j] = "";
                $sum = $sum + 1000*3;
             }
            else
            {
            $sum = $sum + 1000*3;
            $sum = $sum + ($sum * 0.02);
             $arr1[$j] = $sum;
            }

    }
    for($j = 27; $j<=48; $j = $j + 3)
    {

            $sum = $sum + 1000*3;
            $sum = $sum + ($sum * 0.02);
             $arr2[$j] = $sum;



    }
    for($j = 51; $j<=72; $j = $j + 3)
    {

            $sum = $sum + 1000*3;
            $sum = $sum + ($sum * 0.02);
             $arr3[$j] = $sum;



    }
    $arr = array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
    foreach($arr as $key => $val)
    {
        echo '<div style=" width:33%; float:left">';
        foreach($val as $k => $v)
            {

                echo $k."&nbsp;".$v."<br>";

            }
        echo '</div>';

    }
```